# Implement Custom Spring Security Authentication Method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I am building a spring MVC web application, with a user login mechanism. I have used spring-boot to set up my application. To authenticate a user with the database, I followed the following tutorial:

http://justinrodenbostel.com/2014/05/30/part-5-integrating-spring-security-with-spring-boot-web/

Here, spring's inbuilt authentication procedure is used. By specifying

```
auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(datasource);
```

Spring security checks for the user and authorities table and authenticates the user.

I want to override this default behaviour, as I do not have(do not need) an authentication table. Plus, my user table has a lot more columns than the standard three columns, namely username, password and enabled.

How do I override the default implementation?

Also, after the user has logged in, how do I get the information about the user?

Thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of examples of this, search UserDetailsService.

Comment: Check out this page it may help you understand what needs to be done as its got a decent example on it http://igorristic.blogspot.com.au/2014/09/spring-mvc-and-security-basic-setup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either create a custom `AuthenticationProvider` or use `DaoAuthenticationProvider` with your custom `UserDetailsService` implementation.

Here is an example of Spring Java configuration class for the second solution:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    // ...

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(new ShaPasswordEncoder());
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

}
```

Your implementation of `UserDetailsService` interface will contain the logic specific to the domain of your project for retrieving users by their username.

If you need more detailed examples, leave a comment below and I'll update the answer, but this should give you the general idea.

Also i recommend reading through JavaDocs of the aforementioned Spring classes and interfaces.

Comment: good answer; only critic is that MD5 and SHA aren't recommended as hashing functions, rather use Blowfish hashing (the bCryptPasswordEncoder), because it can be adapted as computing power gets cheaper (so cracking passwords gets easier). Details: https://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/