# Spring security and UserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am new to Spring Security and I am trying to implement a custom `UserDetailsService` for authentication. What bothers me, is that this interface contains only one method `loadUserByUsername(String username)` which takes only the username as a parameter and returns a `UserDetails`.

I was wondering why this method does not take any password as a parameter.

How Spring managed to authenticate a user based only on the username?

I am new to Spring security and any clarification on the Api and the authentication process in Spring Security is welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not the job of `UserDetailsService` to authenticate the user. That is responsibility of `AuthenticationProvider`.

For example the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` just uses `UserDetailsService` to load the user by username and then verifies the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` against that user to see if the passwords match.

Have a look at the source code of `DaoAuthenticationProvider` to get an idea of how exactly this is done behind the scenes.

Comment: Do I have to provide an AuthenticationProvider if I have users stored in a database?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use custom UserDetailsService. Look at this answer for details on how to set up authentication manager with your custom UserDetailsService: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285609/implement-custom-spring-security-authentication-method/26286180#26286180

Comment: `UserDetailsSercvice` is used to authorize user and loads user's info from Ldap/DB as required.

if you want to authenticate user against DB then you can write your own custom `AuthenticationProvider` and override `authenticate()` method